# Why do lithium and sodium corrode so easily?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I want to know what is the phenomenon and explanation behind this corrosion. What is the reaction?

Comment: Could you improve your question by including what you know and don't know about these metals and about corrosion? It would help use generate a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ce{2Li + 2H2O -> 2LiOH + H2}$$
$$\ce{2LiOH + CO2 -> Li2CO3 + H2O}$$ 
$$\ce{4Li + O2 -> 2Li2O}$$ 
$$\ce{Li2O + CO2 -> Li2CO3}$$
$$\ce{6Li + N2 -> 2Li3N}$$
Lithium and sodium are reacting with the gases in the air; a destructive physical process.

Comment: A better answer would also include why these metals (and other alkali metals) do these reactions and why other metals (iron, tungsten, cobalt, etc) don't undergo these reactions (or do so much more slowly).